# Child combo box showing values other than the parents combo box selected value's item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

### XAML

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,0,0" Name="comboBoxServer"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerNameList, Mode=OneWay}"   SelectedItem="{Binding Path=serverSelected,  Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">

                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding serverCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=comboBoxServer,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox

<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,0,0" Name="comboBoxDBName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" ItemsSource="{Binding DBNameList}"   SelectionChanged="comboBoxServer_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding Path= fetchServer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
```

### View Model

Parent Combo Box : _ServerNameList
Child Combo box is : _DBNameList

### ViewModel Constructor

```
     public BackUpViewModel()
            {                       
                BackUpContext servObj = new BackUpContext();
                _ServerNameList = servObj.GetServers();     

                serverCommand = new RelayCommand(fetchServer);
            }

public RelayCommand serverCommand { get; set; }
public void fetchServer(object server)
            {
                 BackUpContext db= new BackUpContext();            
                 serverSelected = server.ToString();
                _DBNameList = db.GetDatabases(serverSelected);           
            }
```

> When I Select First Item in Parent Combo Box, The child Combo box is blank. After that when I am selecting second item in parent combo box, the child is showing Items related to first Item in Parent. When I am selecting third item in Parent the child is showing items related to second item in parent combo box.
>
> I don't know why it is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you pls include your xaml?

Comment: @tagaPdyk: <ComboBox Name="comboBoxServer"   ItemsSource="{Binding ServerNameList, Mode=OneWay}"   SelectedItem="{Binding Path=serverSelected,  Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">           
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                  
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding serverCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=comboBoxServer,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>

Comment: @tagaPdyk:  <ComboBox Name="comboBoxDBName"  ItemsSource="{Binding DBNameList}"   SelectionChanged="comboBoxServer_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding Path= fetchServer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>

Comment: Pls edit your question and add the xaml there. The issue here is your 'first' selection, is that correct?

Comment: @tagaPdyk : XAML has been added to the question.

Comment: @tagaPdyk : Initially whatever value i am selecting in Combo box Server, the database combo box is always null, now after that when I am selecting second Item in server box, it display items related to first Item of server box, third item selection shows items related to second item.

Comment: On the nullity, have you tried to breakpoint that area? Its possible that your db.GetDatabases() returns null.

Comment: @tagaPdyk : breakPoint is showing correct values on selected items. I guess the problem that my _DBNameList is not being initialized inside the constructor as _ServerNameList is.  But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: You have to decide which of _ServerNameList is selected and based from that, get _DBNameList.

Comment: @tagaPdyk : For eg : a : 1,2,3 b: 4,5 c: 6,7,8 Now when i am selecting any value in server, the database box is empty. When I select b-> it gives 123, C-> gives 4,5 , a-> 6,7,8

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the values for your second ComboBox.

```
public BackUpViewModel()
{                       
    BackUpContext servObj = new BackUpContext();
   _ServerNameList = servObj.GetServers();     

   // Select the first.
   fetchServer(_ServerNameList.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Comment: Nope. It didn't work for me... database values are not fetching in desired selected values

Comment: Hmmm.. Again, during init of you Vm, what is the value of your dblist shoud be?

Comment: @ tagaPdyk : Initially both boxes are blank & it is how it should be. But problem comes after, When I click on server box and select any values in server box, the database box still is empty, which it should not be, it should have shown items of that selected value. Now when again i am selecting another value in server box, the database list populates but with wrong selected value items.

Comment: For eg : a : 1,2,3    b: 4,5  c: 6,7,8
Now when i am selecting any value in server, the database box is empty. When I select b-> it gives 123, C-> gives 4,5 , a-> 6,7,8